# Navbar not displaying when in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding and busy developing a navbar for a responsive site. When the screen is 100% the menu is visible, but as soon as the browser is dragged smaller it is responsive and the menu is colapsing with a hamburger icon (three stripes). I have attempted to trouble shoot but was unsuccessful thusfar. Any assistance will be appreaciated!

```
        <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
            <a href="" id="navbar__logo">NEXT</a>
            <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar__menu">
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Home </a>
                </li>   
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="Tech.html" class="navbar__links"> Tech </a>
                </li> 
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Products </a>
                </li>   
                <li class="navbar__btn">
                    <a href="/" class="button"> Sign up </a>
                </li>              
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Css:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 58vh;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #131313;
    }

    .navbar__menu:active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 58vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    
    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: #fff;
    }

    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
        
    }

    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
     transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

Java Script:

```
    const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
    const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
    
    menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    });
```

Comment: What is `menuLinks` in your JavaScript?

Comment: Way 1. remove every style on `@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {}` to clear mobile size. -----

Way 2. change `.navbar__menu {opacity: 0}` -> `.navbar__menu {opacity: 1}` to prevent hiding the menu on mobile size. and also add `.navbar__toggle{display: none !important}` into the `@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {}` in order to hide the hamburger toggle button.